# Dom0 can not ping domU in Xen with route mode

Tags: debian, xen

I have a Xen 4.1 on a debian wheezy. Xen is configured with route mode in the *xend-config.sxp* file:
    (network-script network-route)
    (vif-script vif-route)

Dom0's ip is 192.168.xxx.xxx. DomU's ip is 10.1.1.1 .

At the beginning, I could ping domU, when I start it. After a while, counldn't ping it. I found the some of the reasons.

When I start domU, dom0 add a route to 10.1.1.1:

```
# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination Gateway Genmask Flags Metric Ref Use Iface
0.0.0.0 192.168.64.1 0.0.0.0 UG 0 0 0 eth0
**10.1.1.1 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 UH 0 0 0 vif9.0**
192.168.0.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.0.0 U 0 0 0 dom0back
192.168.64.0 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.0 U 0 0 0 eth0
```

I could ping domU during this moment. However, after a while, the route was deleted. I couldn't ping it any more.

```
# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.64.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 dom0back
192.168.64.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

The route to 10.1.1.1 didn't exist any more.

How that happened? I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that Xen created a bridge called Xenbr0(even though you used the routing mode) by default? Check this by entering: `brctl show` on Dom0. You can delete your virtual interfaces from the bridge using: `brctl delif <bridge name> <interface name>` or delete the bridge itself: `brctl delbr <bridge name>`.

Answer (score 0):

the vif-route script is broken, see https://lists.xen.org/archives/html/xen-users/2015-08/msg00003.html

the change which is required:

```
if [ "${ip}" ] && [ "${ipcmd}" ] ; then
```

instead of

```
if [ "${ip}" ] ; then
```